# Как в jQuery перебрать ассоциативный массив?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не работает?

Вот HTML и JavaScript(jQuery)

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready (
  function () {
    $("#vehicles_year_select_id").bind("change", function () {
      $("#vehicles_make_select_id").empty();
        $.get("vehicles_make.php", {vehicles_year_id: $("#vehicles_year_select_id").val()}, function (data) {
          data = data!="" ? JSON.parse(data) : {};
          for(var id in data) {
            $("#vehicles_make_select_id").append($("<option value='" + id + "'>" + data[id] + "</option>"));
          }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="vehicles_make_select_id">
  <option value="-1" disabled selected>Select Make</option>
</select>
```

Вот PHP:

```
if($_GET["vehicles_year_id"] !== -1) {
$dewrq = $_GET["vehicles_year_id"];

$drert = array();
$rerwe = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');

$link = mysqli_connect(
    'localhost',  
    'user',
    'password',   
    'db');

if (!$link) {
printf("Невозможно подключиться к базе данных. Код ошибки: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit;
}

if ($result_id = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM `wpjl_term_taxonomy` WHERE `parent` = '.$dewrq.'')) {

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_id) ){
        array_push($drert, $row['term_id']);
        $cqwer = array_combine($drert, $rerwe);
        }
    $jmsv = json_encode($cqwer);
    echo $jmsv;

    mysqli_free_result($row);
}

mysqli_close($link);}
```

Вот что должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ключ массива должен помещаться в Value, а сам элемент массива в текст option.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот что на деле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоли пусто.

Вроде сам PHP код рабочий. Я задал переменную с определённым значением.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот что получаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Люди добрые, подскажите пожалуйста где я накосячил?

Если вывести в консоль:

```html
$(document).ready (
 function () {
  $("#vehicles_year_select_id").bind("change", function () {
   $("#vehicles_make_select_id").empty();
    $.get("vehicles_make.php", {vehicles_year_id: $("#vehicles_year_select_id").val()}, function (data) {
     data = data!="" ? JSON.parse(data) : {};
      console.log(data);
  });
 });
});
```

То в консоли хрома выдаёт false

Comment: выведи что у тебя в `data`  приходит, возможно нужно передавать data.data в JSON.parse

Comment: @Grundy Я поправил сообщение. Выдаёт false.

Comment: @Grundy Я кажется начал понимать в чём дело. Если много раз кликать и немного подождать то такое ощущение что отвисает и всё-таки работает как мне нужно. Я посмотрел и понял что каким-то боком подглючивает из-за плагина фильтрации - WOOF - WooCommerce Products Filter

Comment: @Grundy Я когда кликаю по селекту и выбираю нужный мне option посылается запрос, но не мой запрос а запрос woof. Как-так почему?

Comment: кто ж знает? :)

Comment: @Grundy А нет, дело не в woof. Я его отключил и оно всё-равно глючит. Что ж за беда?

Comment: если тебе приходит неверный ответ надо посмотреть куда ты ходишь и разобраться с сервером